# why the error message is something like "list object has no attributes *()", instead of "list object has no methods *()"?

Tags: python, python-3.x

All. I understand that when you call a method which does not belong to that object, you will get an error, saying that "list object does not have that attribute". My question is: why does people use attributes here, instead of using methods? I mean, precisely speaking, it should be methods, right? Thank you all.

Comment: If you can't find the attribute... how do you tell if it's a method or not?

Comment: A method _is_ an attribute of a class. It's just a callable attribute.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In an operation like

```
some_list.foo()
```

there are two steps you're thinking of as one. Retrieve the attribute:

```
some_list.foo
```

and call it:

```
             ()
```

Unlike in some other languages, these are completely independent steps. The code responsible for the `some_list.foo` attribute access doesn't know that you're planning to call the attribute. It just sees that you're trying to retrieve an attribute that doesn't exist, and that's what it tells you.

Answer (score 0):

A method *is* an attribute, specifically a callable one. Attribute is a more general term that includes anything scoped to an object. For instance:

```
class Example(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.some_attr = True

    def some_method(self):
        return False

foo = Example()
foo.some_attr    # is an attribute of foo of type boolean
foo.some_method  # is an attribute of foo of type method
```

Answer (score 0):

Because in Python there are no methods in general (methods are just functions attached to classes). Typical invocation looks like this:

```
x.foo (bar)
```

But this is exactly the same as this:

```
m = x.foo
m (bar)
```

The error happens at the first step, and it is clear that at this point `foo` is just an attribute, and attribute getter has no idea what will be done with it later.

Answer (score 0):

Considering the following code:

```
class A:

    def foo():
        return "a"

a = A()
a.bar()
```

When calling `a.bar()` Python produce the following ast (Abstract Syntax Tree):

```
Call(
    func=Attribute(
        value=Name(id='a', ctx=Load()),
        attr='bar',
        ctx=Load()
    ),
    # ...
)
```

The first thing Python tries to do is getting the attribute, and checking if it is callable. If the attribute does not exist, `Attribute` will fail first, resulting in its associated error `A object has no attribute bar`.

Notice it is not saying `A object has no attribute bar()`